# Export emails from Open-Xchange webmail and import them to Horde webmail

Tags: email, webmail, openx

I'm moving hosting and need to move the emails stored with the old domain and hosting. The hosting I want to transfer from uses Open-Xchange for its webmail and the hosting I want to move to uses Horde for their webmail.

Is their an automated way from inside of the Open-Xchange webmail? Is there a way I can do it from inside of Outlook or Mac Mail?

Comment: By the way, if you have direct shell access to the Horde server, there are even tools distributed with Horde that help you migrating groupware data like contacts or events from OpenXchange too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Outlook or any other IMAP client you could simply connect to your mail server,  Then pull the emails to a locally created profile (off the imap server).  Then connect to your new email server and pull them again to its directly.

Based on number of emails this process will TAKE A LONG TIME.

Answer (score 1):

Via the Open-Xchange webmail user interface, you can download a *.zip* file containing multiple emails by doing the following:

1. Mark the checkbox next to each email you want to include in the *.zip* file
2. Click the menu icon above the list of emails
3. Click the "Save as file" link

Your web browser will then display its "Save as..." dialog, which you can use to indicate where you want your web browser to save the *.zip* file containing the selected emails.

The emails (inside the .zip file) will each be in *.eml* format.

[image: Screenshot showing "Save as file" link]